# Div next to div image

Tags: html, css

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6242/4613/)

I want to make description of cat next to its image. Can you help me?

```html
<div id='parent_div_1'>
  <div class='child_div_1'>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYXNLuN8M8-f0TZUM9DIiMD3bNN6B8hyvlyttFrUdN423bn7ZD" alt="null" />
  </div>
  <div class='child_div_2'>
    <pre>
       Name: Caroline
       Age:1;
       Gender: Female;
       Weight: 3kg;
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some basic formatting and float issues, but I fixed for you! Hope this is what you want.

HTML:

```
<div id='parent_div_1'>
   <div class ='child_div_1'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYXNLuN8M8-f0TZUM9DIiMD3bNN6B8hyvlyttFrUdN423bn7ZD" alt="null" />
   </div>
   <div class ='child_div_2'>
      <p>Name: Caroline
         Age:1;
         Gender: Female;
         Weight: 3kg;</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #parent_div_2, #parent_div_3{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;   
    margin-right:10px;
}
.child_div_1{
   float: left;
   border: 1px solid green;
}
.child_div_2{
   float: left;
   height: 50px;
   margin: 30px;
   padding: 30px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/vNVerW)

Comment: thank you very much:) i want to make them side by side with some distance I tried it with margin and padding but i can't succeed can you help me with this one ?

Comment: fixed, see the new demo! You can change the margin on ``.child_div_2`` to get the distance you want. Adjust the padding to get the distance between the border and the element.

Comment: I need distance between image div and description div

Comment: I forgot to hit save xP there check it now.

Comment: Thank you very much again:)

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

CSS:

```
#parent_div_1
{
    margin-right:10px;
}

#parent_div_1 img, #parent_div_1 div
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#parent_div_1 div
{
    margin-right:5px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

and for HTML :

```
<div id='parent_div_1'>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYXNLuN8M8-f0TZUM9DIiMD3bNN6B8hyvlyttFrUdN423bn7ZD" alt="null" />
    <div>Name: Caroline; Age:1; Gender: Female; Weight: 3kg; </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c6242/4615/

Comment: thank you :) I need some border spacing but it doesn't work here.